# auth.statusChange event when user logs in in social plugin (comments)?

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, sdk, comments

I'm using some social plugins on my page (mostly fb:comments) and I'm familiar with Facebook's JavaScript SDK. Now I'm wondering if the JS SDK sends the 'auth.statusChange' if the user logs in to send a comment as I can't get it working...

As everyone likes code, here's an example:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            ...
        });

        function onFBLoginStatusChange(response) {
            // function is never triggered
        }

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', onFBLoginStatusChange);
    }
</script>
<fb:comments href="..."></fb:comments>
```

Now the comments themself work just fine however I hoped that I could get the "auth.statusChange" event when the user logs in to post a comment. I can catch the event if I provide my own login button on the page but I'd like to avoid that.

Is that because Facebook actually renders an iframe for the comments? Is there any way around it?

Comment: I actually have the same exact problem. I also have a separate custom login button that I want to keep in sync, but the auth.statusChange doesn't fire when the user logs in using the 'Login to Facebook to Post a Comment' from the comments widget.